# iOS - How can I get my HealthKit data on two devices?

Tags: iphone, icloud, health-kit

I have my primary iPhone, signed in with iCloud account. This device has a lot of HealthKit data available. I also have my old iPhone(reset to factory settings). I would like to test my app with an older iPhone.

**Is there a way for me to get my HealthKit data to be available on the other device?**

Comment: Why can't use sign-in to your iCloud account on the older iPhone?  It should use your health data from iCloud.

Comment: Thank you, sign in to iCloud worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: Sign in to iCloud on both devices, and enable the Health setting.

Health syncing may not occur immediately. Allow both devices to stay plugged in overnight connected to Wi-Fi.

Comment: I see the old device synced the data, initial testing showed a number of hiccups, but I think they went away after running the app a few times.